# Change the master page from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have a web page named MyPage.aspx and two master page named Home.master and BlanK.master.
By default MyPage.aspx uses Home.master.But based on some condition I need to change the master page from Home.aspx to Blank.master.So, how to do this from code behind in c#?I mean how change the master page from code behind?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set it in the `Pre_Init` event:

```
void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MasterPageFile = "~/Blank.master";
}
```

See http://odetocode.com/Articles/450.aspx for some detail and more options.

Answer (score 8):

put the following line in the Page_PreInit method of your codebehind page:

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    this.Page.MasterPageFile = "~/Blank.master";
}
```